# Possible to use a root data transformation below a square root (< 2) for data normalization

Tags: data-transformation

Is it possible to do a variation of a root data transformation that is below `x^(1/2)`? Are there rules against this - for example: do they need to be whole numbers? Can anyone provide literature on this?

Context of transformation: Transforming to exhibit a normal distribution before applying a specific statistical test.

Example: `x^(1/1.5)`

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=box+cox+-regression+score%3A2

Comment: Re the context: you might want to read https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25738/is-a-log-transformation-a-valid-technique-for-t-testing-non-normal-data/25753#25753 first.